# How can i resolve "Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am studying with 'instagram clone coding by sonny sangha in the youtube.

when i tring to upload the post with firebase, there is a error like this.
i already check similar error solutions in Google, But i cannot resolve the problem.
This is my first time to study with react making a project. Pleas help me out!

Given the following code:

```
    import { useRecoilState } from "recoil";
import { modalState } from "../atoms/modalAtom";
import {Dialog, Transition} from "@headlessui/react";
import { Fragment, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { CameraIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import { db, storage} from "../firebase";
import { 
    addDoc, 
    collection,
    doc,
    serverTimestamp, 
    updateDoc 
} from "@firebase/firestore"; 
import {useSession} from "next-auth/react";
import {ref, getDownloadURL, uploadString } from "@firebase/storage";

function Modal(){

    const {data: session} = useSession();
    const[open, setOpen] = useRecoilState(modalState);
    const filePickerRef =useRef(null);
    const captionRef = useRef(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

    const uploadPost = async() => {
        if(loading) return;

        setLoading(true);

        // 1) Create a post -> add to firestore 'posts' collection
        // 2) get the post id for the newly created post
        // 3) upload the image fo firebase storage with the post id
        // 4) get the download url from db storage and update the original post with img

        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
            username: session.user.username,
            caption: captionRef.current.value,
            profileImg: session.user.image,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp()
        })

        console.log("new doc add with id", docRef.id);

        //3)
        const imageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${docRef.id}/image`);

        await uploadString(imageRef, selectedFile, "data_url").then(
            async (snapshot) => {
            const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
            
            //4)
            await updateDoc(doc(db, 'posts',docRef.id), {
                image: downloadURL
                })
            }
        );

        setOpen(false);
        setLoading(false);
        setSelectedFile(null);

    };


    const addImageToPost = (e) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        if(e.target.files[0]){
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        }

        reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
            setSelectedFile(readerEvent.target.result);
        };
    };

    return (
    <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}> 
        <Dialog
            as='div'
            className='fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto'
            onClose={setOpen}
        >
            <div className="flex items-end justify-center min-h-[800px] sm:min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
                <Transition.Child
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="ease-out duration-300"
                    enterFrom="opacity-0"
                    enterTo="opacity-100"
                    leave="ease-in duration-200"
                    leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                    leaveTo="opacity-0"
                >

                    <Dialog.Overlay 
                        className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
                </Transition.Child>


                <span
                    className="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                >
                    &#8203;
                </span>

                <Transition.Child
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="ease-out duration-300"
                    enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                    enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                    leave="ease-in duration-200"
                    leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                    leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                >
                    <div className="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg px-4 pt-5 
                    pb-4 text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all 
                    sm:align-middle sm:max-w-sm sm:w-full sm:p-6">

                        <div>

                            {selectedFile ? (
                                <img 
                                    src = {selectedFile} 
                                    className="w-full object-contain cursor-pointer"
                                    onClick={() => setSelectedFile(null)} 
                                    alt="" 
                                />

                            ): (

                            <div 
                                onClick = { ()=> filePickerRef.current.click() }
                                className = "mx-auto flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-red-100 cursor-pointer"
                                        >
                                
                                <CameraIcon 
                                    className = "h-6 w-6 text-red-600"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                />
                            </div>

                            )}

                            
                
                            <div>
                                <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-5">
                                    <Dialog.Title
                                        as="h3"
                                        className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium  text-gray-900"
                                        >
                                            Upload a photo
                                    </Dialog.Title>

                                    <div>
                                        <input 
                                            ref={filePickerRef}
                                            type="file"
                                            hidden
                                            onChange={addImageToPost}
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="mt-2">
                                        <input 
                                            className="border-none focus:ring-0 w-full text-center"
                                            type="text"
                                            ref={captionRef}
                                            placeholder="Please enter a caption..."
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {/* flex justify-center space-x-4 mt-4 */}
                            <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-6">
                                <button
                                    type="button"
                                    disabled={!selectedFile}
                                    classname="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 
                                    focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-500 sm:text-sm disabled:bg-gray-300
                                    disabled: cursor-not-allowed hover:disabled:bg-gray-300"
                                    onClick={uploadPost}
                                    >
                                    {loading ? "Uploading..." : "Upload Post"}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Transition.Child>
            </div>
        </Dialog>
    </Transition.Root>
    );
}

export default Modal;
```

The output(error) is:

```
> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
```

This is the firebase.js

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCI5m2ODKR0dwo-1ZuzULMI84UoqpfG_-E",
  authDomain: "instagram-fcc31.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "instagram-fcc31",
  storageBucket: "instagram-fcc31.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "227919580465",
  appId: "1:227919580465:web:a4dbf4f84cd87b59dff410"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Comment: The error message is complaining about `db`.  We can't see what it is based on what you've shown so far.  As the error message says, it needs to be "a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore". Please edit the question to show a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can use to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! you mean i have to add more codes like firebase.js?
(right,,? i am sorry i am the beginner..)

Comment: You've got this import statement: `import { db, storage } from "../firebase";`, but when you showed firebase.js, there are no exports named `db` and `storage`. So either you left them out of the question (in which case you should add them to your question), or they're missing from the actual code (in which case, that's the problem and you should add them to the code).

Comment: wow thank you so much!! i resolved this problem!! thank you for helping me! :)